# How to make my room sorter more random?

Tags: java, random

So I'm working on a program which is supposed to randomly put people in 6 rooms (final input is the list of rooms with who is in each room). So I figured out how to do all that.

```
        //this is the main sorting sequence:
        for (int srtM = 0; srtM < Guys.length; srtM++) {
        done = false;
        People newMove = Guys[srtM]; //Guys is an array of People 
        while (!done) {
            newMove.rndRoom(); //sets random number from 4 to 6
            if (newMove.getRoom() == 4 && !room4.isFull()) {
                room4.add(newMove); //adds person into the room4 object rList
                done = true;
            } else if (newMove.getRoom() == 5 && !room5.isFull()) {
                room5.add(newMove);
                done = true;
            } else if (newMove.getRoom() == 6 && !room6.isFull()) {
                room6.add(newMove);
                done = true;
            }
        }
```

The problem now is that the code for reasons I don't completely understand (something with the way I wrote it here) is hardly random. It seems the same people are put into the same rooms almost every time I run the program. For example me, I'm almost always put by this program into room 6 together with another one friend (interestingly, we're both at the end of the Guys array). So how can I make it "truly" random? Or a lot more random than it is now?

Thanks in advance!

Forgot to mention that "rndRoom()" does indeed use the standard Random method (for 4-6) in the background:

```
public int rndRoom() {
    if (this.gender == 'M') {
        this.room = (rnd.nextInt((6 - 4) + 1)) + 4;
    }
    if (this.gender == 'F') {
        this.room = (rnd.nextInt(((3 - 1) + 1))) + 1;
    }
    return this.room;
}
```

Comment: We wouldn't be able to help you without seeing more of your code. What does the `rndRoom()` method on `People` do, for example? Why are you only assigning people to rooms 4, 5, and 6? What happened to 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Could you please post the _rndRoom_ method?

Comment: Yeah sure - so the rndRoom method just relies on a standard Random nextInt action (which is inside the People class). Rooms 1-3 are for girls, the code example here is for rooms 4-6 which are for the guys.

Comment: The question is seems to make a random thing more randomly, it make no sense. How you quantize it?

Comment: What do you mean quantize?

Comment: Added rndRoom() to the main post.

Comment: I mean, you can't give random a level or a class to say how random is it.
You can't do compare if it is already random.

Comment: With the way I wrote it I'd expect it too look random. But it's not - when I run the progam repeatedly it seems to put some people into the same rooms almost every time. Something is strange here.

Comment: There is no problem with any of this code, maybe critical more code from Room or Person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I figured out why the results don't seem very random. So the room sorter works based on an alphabetical people list of 18 guys. There are only 3 guy rooms (rooms 4, 5 and 6) So each guy has a 1 in 3 chance to be put in say, room 6. But each person could only possibly be in 2 of the 6 spots in each room (depending on where they are in the list).

The first two people for example, could each only be in either the first or second spot of each room. By "spot" I mean their place in the room list which is printed in the end. Me on the other hand am second last on the list, so at that point I could only be in either the last or second last spot of each room.

Sorry if it's confusing but I figured out this is the reason the generated room lists don't appear very random - it's because only the same few people could be put in each room spot every time. The lists are random though, it's just the order in which people appear in each list which is not random.

So in order to make the lists *look* more random I had to make people's positions in the room random too. So the way I solved this is by adding a shuffler action which mixes the Person arrays:

```
    public static void shuffle(Person[] arr) {
        Random rgen = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int randPos = rgen.nextInt(arr.length);
            Person tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[randPos];
            arr[randPos] = tmp;
        }
    }
```

TL;DR the generated room lists were random - but since the order of the people that got put into the rooms wasn't random the results didn't look very random. In order to solve this I shuffled the Person arrays.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to be more random try doing something with the `Random` method, do something like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        int roomChoice = random.nextInt(5) + 1;
        roomChoice += 1;
    }
```

of course this is not exactly the code you will want to use, this is just an example of how to use the `Random` method, change it to how you want to use it.

Also, the reason I did `random.nextInt(5) + 1;` is because if `random.nextInt(5) + 1;` gets you a random number from `0 to 5`, so if you want a number from `1 to 6` you have to add 1, pretty self explanatory.

---

On another note, to get "truly" random is not as easy as it seems, when you generate a "random" number it will use something called `Pseudo random number generation`, this, is basically these programs produce endless strings of single-digit numbers, usually in base 10, known as the decimal system. When large samples of pseudo-random numbers are taken, each of the 10 digits in the set {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} occurs with equal frequency, even though they are not evenly distributed in the sequence.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention (was just coming back here to add that and already two answers!) but rndRoom() does indeed use the Random method in the backgroud. It draws from 4-6 - that part is random. It's something later that is not random for some reason...

Comment: @RoiB If you are using the `Random` method, then the reason your program doesn't feel very random is because you are getting from 4 - 6, which is two numbers, giving you a 50% chance to get either, which after time doesn't seem so random. Also, the way humans perceive thing, many things don't seem random, since our brains try to search for patterns in almost everything.

Comment: By 4-6 I meant all 3 numbers, so 1/3 chance to get each. Sure it might be my mind messing with me, but I really do think there's something wrong here - it seems almost every other time I get put in room #6 in exactly bed #5 together with the same friend of mine who gets put in bed #6. That me and that friend are the last two people in the Guys array is leading me to think there's definitely something with the way I wrote this code which is causing it to be hardly random (it seems it kinda folows the array list in a certain way).

Comment: @RoiB If you show us your `rndRoom` method it would be a lot easier to well whether or not you messed something up.

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with it, but one thing I would change is, instead of doing `(6 - 4)` just do `2`, it is the exact same thing, and it looks nicer.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong with code you didn't post.
I've build a working example with what your classes might be, and it is distributing pretty randomly:

http://pastebin.com/u8sZRxi6

Comment: Yeah that must be it. This is the first time I asked a question so I wasn't sure though how much code should I post, posting everything could be overwhelming but on the other hand if I don't do that people here might miss out on important bits. Anyway thanks for your code! It's interesting to see a slightly different (probably better) implementation than what I did. I'll try to learn out of that as much as I can.